# How to do a page redirect using javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup

I am currently using this code which is working great except for iframes :

```
var domains = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com", "domain3.com"];

if (domains.indexOf(document.location.hostname) == -1 && document.cookie.indexOf('redirected=1') == -1) {
    document.cookie = "redirected=1";
    window.location.replace('http://domain1.com');
}
alert("Join our main website ==> http://domain1.com");
```

but when my website is iframed in other sites the code doesn't work, and if i use `window.location.open` or `window.location.href` it will be blocked by popup blockers.

is there another way to do a redirect or a page open without being stopped by popup blockers or just a redirect that can redirect the whole page that has the iframe to another page ?

Thanks in advance.

-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "top" property of window to access the parent window,
like:

```
window.top.location="http://domain1.com";
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now if you can help me more, i want the cookie to be registered only if the user is joining through one of the 3 domains, else to go top location without saving cookie !
thanks again

Comment: Cookies are domain restricted, so you cannot redirect to another top level domain and store a cookie that will be accessible from the page you redirected to. But you could add a hashtag or get parameter to your URL that you can parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try an approach with creation of meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/;">
```

Or in case domain in urls of your iframe it is possible to access the parent document and hence update the iframe's src.

Comment: I mean you can create a tag in JS (see document.createElement, appendChild) and add it to the <HEAD> section of a document.

Comment: what i meant is that i need it as pure javascipt .js file without any html